# cocos2d-x animation play in loop

Tags: cocos2d-x

A animation move from point a to b, in the movement, the animation need to be play in loop. For example, a bullet move to a point and this bullet is a animation which should be played in loop.

```
CCSequence::create(
  CCSpawn::createWithTwoActions(
    CCTargetedAction::create(sprite, CCMoveTo::create(3.0f, point_a)), 
    CCTargetedAction::create(sprite, CCRepeatForever::create(CCAnimate::create(animation)))
),0);
```

But CCRepeatForever can not be a member of action sequence.
So how to do it? I use sequence because there are others actions be queued (omitted above)

Comment: separate the actions, one for move the other for animation, or if the anim plays only after the move, sequence another spawn that creates the repeated anim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't need to use ccspawn for this.. nor ccsequence just run both actions separately on the object.

```
CCSprite *newSprite=CCSprite::create("imageName");

CCAnimation *animation=CCAnimation::create();

//..some code to add frames to this animation object..

//to repeat for indefinite time you could setLoops to -1 or use CCRepeatForever class    //like this..
//1:

animation->setLoops(-1);
newSprite->runAction(CCAnimate:create(animation));

//or..

//2:

newSprite->runAction(CCRepeatForever:create(CCAnimate:create(animation)));

//now to translate this sprite simultaneously use this.

newSprite->runAction(CCMoveTo::create(3.0,point_a));
```